# Signed and unsigned machine word types

Tags: c, integer, unsigned, signed

I need a pair of standard integer types, signed and unsigned, that correspond to (a reasonable interpretation of) the machine word size, and that are guaranteed to be the same size as each other.

On platforms with a clean address model, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` fit the bill, so using those is certainly a possibility.

However, there is a possibility that the code in question may need to run on various embedded systems. I'm guessing some of these still use CPUs with a 286-style architecture where the largest efficient integer type is smaller than a pointer - please correct me if this is not so - but if it is, then there is a case to be made for using the smaller integer type.

That smaller integer type would presumably correspond to `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` - but are those types guaranteed to be the same size as each other? I do need to be able to convert back and forth between the signed and unsigned type without loss.

Is there something else I should be considering?

Comment: Why do you need something that is machine-word-sized? Perhaps you should make clear the actual constraints that your application is placing on your code, and we can discuss how to satisfy those constraints without trying to frame it in terms of machine words.

Comment: Because it needs to be suitable for indexing arrays, tracking the size of allocated memory chunks and suchlike.

Comment: If your constraint is that it needs to be large enough to handle arbitrary addresses and the differences between them, then it seems clear that (u)intptr_t and ptrdiff_t, et al. are the only appropriate types to use. That's what they're for.

Comment: @rwallace - On a 286 an `int` is still large enough to hold the size of a memory segment, even if the address is larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided zmccord is right, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are the types that are both guaranteed to be available, and clearly and unambiguously sufficient. If a particular variable needs to be smaller than that for a particular platform, it can be declared with the specific size it needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `size_t` and `ssize_t.`

*Update:*

This is certainly what `typedef` is for, so:

```
typedef size_t uword_t;
typedef ssize_t word_t;
```

If you ever come across a system that has the C99 `size_t` but not the Posix `ssize_t` then you can either:

1. Conditionally define `word_t` just once for that system *-or-*
2. Perhaps supply your own `<unistd.h>` for that system. It can define `ssize_t` with full knowledge of the local environment and also clean up any other missing Posixness you run into.

Comment: `ssize_t` comes with POSIX and not with C, so it is not clear that it is always defined, in particular on embedded systems there might be problems, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, at first glance this looked like the right solution, but at second glance it doesn't seem to be sufficiently portable.

Answer (score 1):

Why no just use `int` and `unsigned int`?

C99 6.2.5/6 Types

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned) that **uses the same amount of storage** (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements

Comment: The only specification requirement for `int` is that it is at least 16 bits, isn't it?

Comment: Because on some platforms, int doesn't correspond to the machine word size (e.g. on 64-bit Windows, int is still 32 bit).

Comment: An int is sometimes 32 bits on embedded processors where 32 bits is far too big; avr-gcc has 32-bit ints on an 8-bit processor, for example.